# How can I make my Vigenère Cipher ignore spaces in the original message

Tags: python, vigenere

Im trying to make a Vigenère Cipher but I can't seem to find a way to implement a feature that ignores in-putted white spaces when entering the message and then printing the final for example: I enter the starting message: "python computing" then I enter the key as: "stack" I expect to get if the program ignores spaces in the original message: "isukzg wppannjqr" but instead I get: "isukzgwppannjqr". Anyone know how I can solve this. I have considered using ords but I havent found a way to implement it. Code below:

```
def translateMessage(key, message, mode):
    translated = ""

    keyIndex = 0
    key = key.upper()

    for symbol in message:
        xyz = alphabet.find(symbol.upper())
        if xyz != -1:
            if mode == 'encrypt' or 'e':
                xyz += alphabet.find(key[keyIndex]) + 1
            elif mode == 'decrypt' or 'd':
                xyz -= alphabet.find(key[keyIndex]) + 1

            xyz %= len(alphabet)

            if symbol.isupper():
                translated += alphabet[xyz]
            elif symbol.islower():
                translated += alphabet[xyz].lower()

            keyIndex += 1
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0

    return translated

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_user_inputs()
```

Comment: You explicitly ignore all symbols not found in `alphabet` (`xyz = alphabet.find(symbol.upper())`, `if xyz != -1:`), which includes ignoring space. Why would you expect to have a space in your output if you ignore appending it to it?

Comment: How do I only allow spaces then? Would I use x.isspace()?

Comment: `mode == 'decrypt' or 'd'` should be `mode == 'decrypt' or mode == 'd'` or `mode in ['decrypt', 'd']`. Also consider `'decrypt'.startswith(mode)`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I tried these and I got back a syntax error. While I was testing these I also noticed that the decrypt is the same as the encrypt. Im not sure why this isn't working since I have the `xyz -=` after the decrypt elif.

Comment: I am having trouble believing that the syntax error is in mutt suggestion. While your current syntax is legal, it does not do at all what you seem to thing it does.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add an else statement in `translateMessage()` to add the space to the output like this

```
def translateMessage(key, message, mode):
    translated = ""

    keyIndex = 0
    key = key.upper()

    for symbol in message:
        xyz = alphabet.find(symbol.upper())
        if xyz != -1:
            if mode == 'encrypt' or 'e':
                xyz += alphabet.find(key[keyIndex]) + 1
            elif mode == 'decrypt' or 'd':
                xyz -= alphabet.find(key[keyIndex]) + 1

            xyz %= len(alphabet)

            if symbol.isupper():
                translated += alphabet[xyz]
            elif symbol.islower():
                translated += alphabet[xyz].lower()

            keyIndex += 1
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0
        else : translated += symbol #this will add space as it is

    return translated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do better than that, this code can even return the format along with the spaces, Eg. Capital Letters, Lowercase Letters!

```
def shift_dict(Caesar, Shift):
  dic_len = len(Caesar)
  Shift = Shift % dic_len
  list_dic = [(k,v) for k, v in iter(Caesar.items())]
  Shifted = {
    list_dic[x][0]: list_dic[(x - Shift) % dic_len][1]
    for x in range(dic_len)
  }
  return Shifted

Viginere = {
  "A":0,
  "B":1,
  "C":2,
  "D":3,
  "E":4,
  "F":5,
  "G":6,
  "H":7,
  "I":8,
  "J":9,
  "K":10,
  "L":11,
  "M":12,
  "N":13,
  "O":14,
  "P":15,
  "Q":16,
  "R":17,
  "S":18,
  "T":19,
  "U":20,
  "V":21,
  "W":22,
  "X":23,
  "Y":24,
  "Z":25
}
VFU = {
  0:"A",
  1:"B",
  2:"C",
  3:"D",
  4:"E",
  5:"F",
  6:"G",
  7:"H",
  8:"I",
  9:"J",
  10:"K",
  11:"L",
  12:"M",
  13:"N",
  14:"O",
  15:"P",
  16:"Q",
  17:"R",
  18:"S",
  19:"T",
  20:"U",
  21:"V",
  22:"W",
  23:"X",
  24:"Y",
  25:"Z"
}
VFL = {
  0:"a",
  1:"b",
  2:"c",
  3:"d",
  4:"e",
  5:"f",
  6:"g",
  7:"h",
  8:"i",
  9:"j",
  10:"k",
  11:"l",
  12:"m",
  13:"n",
  14:"o",
  15:"p",
  16:"q",
  17:"r",
  18:"s",
  19:"t",
  20:"u",
  21:"v",
  22:"w",
  23:"x",
  24:"y",
  25:"z"
}

Asker = int(input("Do you want to... 1. Encode, or 2. Decode? "))
X = 0
Lister = []
Text = list(str(input("")))
Key = list(str(input("")).upper())
Z = 0

if Asker == 1:
  for i in range(len(Text)):
    Shift = Viginere[Key[(Z % len(Key))]]
    if Text[X].isalpha():
      LetterNum = Viginere[Text[X].upper()]
      Helper = (LetterNum + Shift) % 26
      if Text[X].isupper():
        Lister.append(VFU[Helper])
      else:
        Lister.append(VFL[Helper])
    else:
      Lister.append(Text[X])
      Z -= 1
    X += 1
    Z += 1
  print(*Lister, sep = "")
elif Asker == 2:
  for i in range(len(Text)):
    Shift = Viginere[Key[(Z % len(Key))]]
    if Text[X].isalpha():
      LetterNum = Viginere[Text[X].upper()]
      Helper = (LetterNum - Shift) % 26
      if Text[X].isupper():
        Lister.append(VFU[Helper])
      else:
        Lister.append(VFL[Helper])
    else:
      Lister.append(Text[X])
      Z -= 1
    X += 1
    Z += 1
  print(*Lister, sep = "")
```

This will solve your problem easily, and it will even ask you for the input of the string and the key! It is the definition of python magic.

Comment: You can make this much more concise by doing `VFU = dict((v, k) for k, v in Viginere.items())` and `VFL = dict((v, k.lower()) for k, v in Viginere.items())`